# Which is the subspace of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb C$ be the field of complex numbers and $n$ be a positive integer ($n\geq 2$). Let $V$ be the vector space of all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb C$.

Which of following set of matrices $A \in V$ are subspaces of $V$?

1. all invertible $A$?
2. all non invertible $A$?

For first, i think that it is not a subspace because if $A$ is invertible and $B$ is invertible that doesn't always mean that $A+B$ is invertible, since $(A+B)^{-1}$ is not equal to $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$.
Also $0$ won't belong to set of all invertible matrices.

For the $2^{nd}$, i think it is not a subspace but can someone explain?
And am i correct for the first part?

Comment: For the first part:  the argument that $0$ isn't in the set is an excellent demonstration that it isn't a subspace.  The bit about inverses is too vague.  For the second part...Hint:  can you think of two matrices each with determinant $0$ which add to the identity matrix?

Comment: The fact that $(A+B)^{-1} \neq A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ doesn't imply that subset 1 is not a subspace.  You need an explicit counterexample, such as your observation that the zero matrix is not in this set.

Comment: The second part: the sum of two non-invertible matrices may be invertible. Take $A=diag(1,0,0,\ldots ,0)$ and $B=diag(0,1,1,\ldots ,1)$. Then $A+B$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: A topological approach would be to show that the considered subsets are not closed, contradicting the fact that any linear subspace is closed. (But this is way more complicated than showing off an explicit example as mentioned above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first set is not a subspace because the zero matrix is not invertible, as you said.

For the second case: consider the following counterexample: let $A=E_{11}$ and $B=E_{22}$, both of them are not invertible, but their sum is the identiy matrix, so the second subset is not close under addition.